# Google App Engine, uploading videos, python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, upload, dropbox, google-drive-api

I am writing an app that lets users upload videos to my site, so i can edit them and sent back to them. I am using google app engine and python. I have read about blobs and stuff but i think is still need a little bit of further explanation.

How it exactly works?

I have written some code using the google blob example code so it seems like files are uploading. However, I dont know how to access them. I dont even know where they are saved.

here is my form

```
<form method="POST" action="%s" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Upload file: <input type="file" name="file" /><br />
    </br>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"/>
  </form>
```

and here are my handlers:

```
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'
from google.appengine.dist import use_library
use_library('django', '1.2')

import os
import logging
import cgi
import datetime
import urllib
import wsgiref.handlers
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
from util.sessions import Session
from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.ext import blobstore
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import blobstore_handlers

# A Model for a User
class User(db.Model):
  account = db.StringProperty()
  password = db.StringProperty()
  name = db.StringProperty()

# A helper to do the rendering and to add the necessary
# variables for the _base.htm template
def doRender(handler, tname = 'index.html', values = { }):
  logging.info('doRender(' + tname + ')')
  temp = os.path.join(
      os.path.dirname(__file__),
      'templates/' + tname)
  logging.info(temp)
  if not os.path.isfile(temp):
    return False

  # Make a copy of the dictionary and add the path and session
  newval = dict(values)
  newval['path'] = handler.request.path
  handler.session = Session()
  if 'username' in handler.session:
     newval['username'] = handler.session['username']
  logging.info(newval)
  outstr = template.render(temp, newval)
  handler.response.out.write(outstr)
  return True


class LoginHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):

  def get(self):
    doRender(self, 'login.html')

  def post(self):
    self.session = Session()
    acct = self.request.get('account')
    pw = self.request.get('password')
    logging.info('Checking account='+acct+' pw='+pw)

    self.session.delete_item('username')
    self.session.delete_item('userkey')

    if pw == '' or acct == '':
      doRender(
          self,
          'login.html',
          {'error' : 'Please specify Account and Password'} )
      return

    que = db.Query(User)
    que = que.filter('account =',acct)
    que = que.filter('password = ',pw)

    results = que.fetch(limit=1)

    if len(results) > 0 :
      user = results[0]
      self.session['userkey'] = user.key()
      self.session['username'] = acct
      doRender(self,'index.html',{ } )
    else:
      doRender(
          self,
          'login.html',
          {'error' : 'Incorrect password'} )

class AddUserHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):

  def get(self):
    doRender(self, 'adduser.html')

  def post(self):
    self.session = Session()
    name = self.request.get('name')
    acct = self.request.get('account')
    pw = self.request.get('password')
    logging.info('Adding account='+acct)

    if pw == '' or acct == '' or name == '':
      doRender(
          self,
          'adduser.html',
          {'error' : 'Please fill in all fields'} )
      return

    # Check if the user already exists
    que = db.Query(User).filter('account =',acct)
    results = que.fetch(limit=1)

    if len(results) > 0 :
      doRender(
          self,
          'adduser.html',
          {'error' : 'Account Already Exists'} )
      return

    # Create the User object and log the user in
    newuser = User(name=name, account=acct, password=pw);
    pkey = newuser.put();
    self.session['username'] = acct
    self.session['userkey'] = pkey
    doRender(self,'index.html',{ })

class LogoutHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):

  def get(self):
    self.session = Session()
    self.session.delete_item('username')
    self.session.delete_item('userkey')
    doRender(self, 'index.html')

class UploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
    def post(self):
        upload_files = self.get_uploads('file')  # 'file' is file upload field in the form
        blob_info = upload_files[0]
        self.redirect('/serve/%s' % blob_info.key())

class ServeHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
    def get(self, resource):
        resource = str(urllib.unquote(resource))
        blob_info = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(resource)
        self.send_blob(blob_info)

class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):        

  def get(self):
    if doRender(self,self.request.path) :
      return
    doRender(self,'index.html')

def main():
  application = webapp.WSGIApplication([
     ('/login', LoginHandler),
     ('/add-user', AddUserHandler),
     ('/logout', LogoutHandler),
     ('/upload', UploadHandler),
     ('/serve/([^/]+)?',ServeHandler),
     ('/.*', MainHandler)],
     debug=True)
  wsgiref.handlers.CGIHandler().run(application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Can someone help me figure this out? Also, is there any option to save this files directly on my google drive or dropbox?

Thanks for help

Comment: Have you tried googling for "App Engine Blobstore" or "Google Drive API"?! You might just find some useful results ...

Comment: As i said I did use google app engine blobstore code and I wouldnt ask question without doing some research before. Thank you for your help tho

Comment: What is exactly your question? Don't just give us a wall of code and ask vague things like "Can someone help me figure this out?", we do not know what is it that you want to figure out.

Comment: "is there any option to save this files directly on my google drive or dropbox?" thats one of my questions.I gave my code because i figure out that it might be useful since people were marking this question as not valuable or not providing enough detail.

Answer (score 1):

You can access blobstore file data using the [BlobReader](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/blobreaderclass) class which behave like a Python file object.

For example:

```
upload_files = self.get_uploads('file')
blob_info = upload_files[0]
f = blob_info.open() # Return a BlobReader
content = f.read() # Read the entire file content into memory
```

You can use the [Drive SDK](https://developers.google.com/drive/) to save file on Google Drive, you can find a sample app for Google App Engine [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/python)

Comment: so how should i access it on my computer? sorry i have never written an app to manage files.

Comment: blobstore files are hosted on App Engine, you can serve them using the `ServeHandler` you posted in your question.

Comment: One more question. Is there a file size limit for blobreader?

Comment: The default free quota for Blobstore Stored Data is 5 GB, there is not maximum for paid application. Also note that the maximum size that can be read in 1 API call is 32MB, so 1 read function call could result in multiple API calls.